# How to emulate keyboard on GNU/Linux?

Tags: bash, jvm, linux-device-driver

How to emulate keyboard on GNU/Linux? I want to be able to write a program with Java or Bash that emulates actual keyboard events. Like CTRL button or say "a" etc.

Comment: Look at the `hid-replay` user space tool.

Comment: In Java, you would have to use [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)